# How to use NLog in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, nlog

I want to use NLog in my Xamarin.Droid project.  I installed NLog.Config and dependencies and move NLog.config and NLog.xsd manually to Assets folder and change NLog.config build action to AndroidAsset.

As you can see in [Load automatically NLog.config from Assets folder](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#xamarin-assets) I guess there is no problem to put NLog.config into Assets folder.

After that I change NLog.config like below

```xml
<targets>
    <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" layout="${longdate} ${callsite} ${level} ${message}"/>
</targets>
<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" />
</rules>
```

After that I write some code like below for write some log in Console

```cs
ILogger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
for (int c = 0; c < 1000; ++c)
    logger.Debug("Hi there");
```

But after that I could not see any my messages in Android Device Logging or Output tab when "Show output from" set to Debug.

Do I look to the right places?

Comment: Try to set `minlevel` to `Debug` in your config file, this should help you.

Comment: Also see [Nlog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#log-levels) levels

Comment: @Anton yes you right it is my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your config says minlevel `info`:

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" />
```

but your are writing `debug` level. Which is below `info`.

```
logger.Debug("Hi there");
```

So change your logger rule to: (level name & attribute names are case insensitive)

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="debug" writeTo="console" />
```

Comment: Is it good way to place NLog.config to Assets? or it is bad practice?

Comment: I think it is, but not sure as it's more Xamarin question

Comment: Instead of using Android Asset, then use embedded resource that should work on all Xamarin Platforms: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Explicit-NLog-configuration-loading

Answer (score 1):

NLog v5 no longer automatically scans for NLog.config in the Androids Assets-folder.

Either perform explicit loading of the NLog.config from the Assets-folder, or consider embedding the NLog.config as Assembly-Ressource:

```cs
NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAssemblyResource(typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Explicit-NLog-configuration-loading

Notice [NLog.Targets.MauiLog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Targets.MauiLog) can also be used for platform specific output:

- Android - Android.Util.Log / LogCat
- Apple iOS / MacOS - Unified Logging OSLog (replacement of print and NSLog)